# Converting total station points to cartesian coordinates

Tags: total-station

I have a set of points which have been downloaded from a total station instrument. These data points are already in excel sheets and the issue now is how to convert these points (easting, northing and elevation) to cartesian coordinates in order to use for modeling purposes.

Comment: What software do you have access to?

Comment: If you have eastings, northings, and elevation - the data are already in a cartesian coordinate system. What are you trying to achieve? Is it buildings you're trying to model, geological processes, etc.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242820/total-station-data

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Eastings & Northings in the Excel sheet, and know the datum, you can "create feature class from xy data" in ArcCatalog.  You'll need to save to .csv format, and assign column headers (no special characters in the headers  except "underscore" ... no spaces, etc, etc).  Alternatively, if you have Civil 3D, you can pull in total station data in to that environment as well.  Assigning coordinate systems, etc is a tad more difficult (I prefer to do this with ESRI). At any rate, before I attempt to explain any further, let me know if you have access to any ESRI products (ex-ArcView, etc), or AutoCAD Civil 3D?  If so, I can give you a hand with this one.
Take care
Dan